# Block specific images so they won't load

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I want my extension to block two images from loading.

I thought this could easily be achieved by using the following in the *content.js*

```
$("#rated-image").remove(); //id of one image
$(".blur-mask").remove(); //class of other image
```

and setting `run_at` to `document_start`. But it seems to not do anything.

When using `document_end` it executes the content.js so it's not a problem with the code.

I can't imagine a way to do this and google didn't give an answer as well.

So what I want is that when the page starts loading the images get removed before they have a chance to load.

Comment: Please [edit] the question to be on-topic: include a **complete** [mcve] that *duplicates the problem*. Including a *manifest.json*, some of the background/content/popup scripts/HTML. Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include: ►the desired behavior, ►a specific problem or error *and* ►the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: "**How to create a [mcve]**", [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and [ask].

Comment: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webRequest

Comment: For document_start to work you need to use MutationObserver.

Comment: @DanielHerr, using webRequest actually worked perfectly. I think the problem was that the _content.js_ would only load with the page. Since I can make the _background.js_ always run in the background it is able to block the Images.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure what you're trying to do. If you can get away with just setting display: none !important and specifically target where you want to hide your images with only css, it'll be less costy than a javascript loop.

I also included the javascript (jQuery) solution.

Maybe if you can shed light on what you're trying to do, I can direct you to an optimal solution.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  // this deletes all images from the dom
  $("img").each(function(){
    $(this).remove();
  });
});
```

```css
.i-want-images-hidden-here img {
  display: none !important; /* this only targets imgs inside said container. You can remove .i-want-images-hidden-here before img to hide every image on your page */
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="i-want-images-hidden-here">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" />
  <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" />
  <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" />
  <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" />
  <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" />
  <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" />
</div>
```

Comment: I'm trying to remove the images so they won't load. I have a AutoHotKey script for a website but since my internet isn't that fast I want the images to be blocked so the website loads faster. There're already extensions that block all images or block certain URLs but I only want to block some images and blocking a URL doesn't seem to work when it's set as an image source. So just making it invisible won't work for me.

Comment: @KonradStüwe Then you want to apply my code before the page loads. I'll update my answer

Comment: @KonradStüwe Come to think of it. I don't know if I can do that. Initially I thought I can just add a script in the <head> that loops through every image with vanilla javascript (jquery isn't loaded yet) and removes it, but then I thought about it further... how do you remove something that isn't there yet? Maybe someone else can shed some light.